# PC-Lint Exclude External folder

Tags: c, gcc, pc-lint

I am running the pc lint misra checks on my project. 
When I execute the program the output is huge because it includes all the bsp files from arm. How do I get pc-lint to exclude a whole directory. In the code when I include a header file from outside the project I use `<>` instead of `""`

i.e. `#include <arm_driver.h>`.

I thought this was enough. Is their another step missing?
These are the additional parameters I have passed

```
+libclass(angle, foreign)
-e686
-wlib(0)
```

And with the command `vf` I can see that all the external directory files are being treated as library headers.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed the issue.
Comment out all the explicit +elib lines in the corresponding .lnt file.

i.e. replace all instances of `+elib` with `//+elib`